# Disable iCloud after changing Apple ID email address

Tags: ipad, icloud, email, apple-id, find-my-iphone

I previously had my Apple ID set up with the email address `old@a.com`, and I enabled iCloud and Find my iPad on my iPad with this Apple ID.  Then, at some point later, I changed the email address on my Apple ID to `new@b.com` -- it's the same Apple ID account, I just changed the email address on it. Now I'd like to disable iCloud and Find my iPad on my iPad, but it won't let me.

In particular, Settings >> iCloud on my iPad still lists the old email address `old@a.com`.  When I try to sign out of iCloud or disable Find my iPad on my iPad, my iPad prompts me for the password corresponding to `old@a.com`.  However, no Apple ID for `old@a.com` currently exists, and my iPad won't accept my password.  It's prompting me for the password for an email address that no longer exists.

My current hypothesis is that the iPad got confused when I changed the email address on my Apple ID, and never updated the email address it has associated with iCloud on the iPad.

How do I fix this?

(Even more confusingly, I can log into the `new@b.com` iCloud account via a browser and see my iPad listed under Settings >> My Devices and listed under Find iPhone via the web iCloud interface for `new@b.com`.  I went to Find my iPhone via the iCloud web interface and removed my iPad from Find iPhone on there, but back on my iPad, iCloud and Find my iPad show up as enabled on my iPad's Settings app.)

Comment: Changing the primary email address does not change the ID itself. It's also not possible for an ID to 'not exist'. Apple IDs go on forever, whether you use them or not. What's not completely clear from your question is quite what you actually did - simply change the primary, or set up a separate ID… or indeed both.

Comment: @Tetsujin, thanks!  I'm pretty sure that I only changed the email address on the ID, but did not set up a separate ID.  Is there a way I could make that clearer in the question?

Comment: Actually the procedure is now different, deleting my previous comment, here is the apple support page for the issue https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203828

Comment: Ahh, I see what I think is where the confusion arises… the "old ID" is actually **still** old@a.com even though its email address is now new@b.com. The ID itself never changes, the login is still old@a.com, whatever the email address is. Your Apple ID in fact doesn't need to be a current or even valid email address.. or actually even an email address at all - but once set up, that's what it is, forever, whatever you do to the data behind it.